# How to transfer ArrayLists of Strings between two Android phones?

Tags: android, arraylist, p2p

I am developing a trading card game app that allows PVP play. To populate the battlefield GridView of the opponent, I need the app to be able to receive several ArrayLists of Strings from the opposing player and be able to send the same kind of ArrayLists to the opponent for the same reason.

A web server would simply be too slow for this, as it needs to happen very quickly. How would I go about doing this via a P2P connection? It seems that with Bluetooth pairing, the phone's Bluetooth framework limits what other Android phones it can pair with, so I'd like to avoid that.

Is there a way for me to simply have the two player phones communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0):

I this is what you are looking for:
[android.net.wifi.p2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)